# Loading a XML, but for asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, xmldocument

I need to load an XML document into my `Dictionary<string,string> object`.

XML looks like:

```
<nodes>
<node id="123">
   <text>text goes here</text>
</node>
</nodes>
```

How can I do this using XmlDocument?

I want readability over performance, and I find XmlReader to be hard to read b/c you have to keep checking the node type.

Comment: What's the key and what's the value for a single dictionary entry?

Comment: key = id, value is 'text' node.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ID is the key and the value of the `<text>` node is the value, you can use LINQ:

```
XDocument xDoc;
using(StringReader sr = new StringReader("thexml"))
{
    xDoc = XDocument.Load(sr);
}
myDictionary = xDoc.Descendants("node").ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("id").Value, x => x.Descendants("text").First().Value);
```

Comment: Except, of course, for the part where that is the 3.5 framework and he wants 2.0...

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a reason why XML parsing has improved since 2.0, but if you just want a sample that parses that fragment without using `XmlReader`, this should work. I'm sure there are other ways of doing this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(@"<nodes><node id=""123""><text>text goes here</text></node><node id=""321""><text>more text goes here</text></node></nodes>");

foreach (XmlNode nodes in doc.GetElementsByTagName("nodes"))
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes.ChildNodes)
    {
        XmlNodeList list = node.SelectNodes("text");
        if (list.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}='{1}'\n", node.Attributes["id"].Value, list[0].InnerText);
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Done.");
Console.ReadKey();
```